# Deriving Boyle's law from only the Gay-Lussac laws

Tags: thermodynamics

My physics professor during a lecture presumably mathematically derived Boyle's law from the two Gay-Lussac laws for ideal gasses. What he said is also printed in his own textbook.

He states that, given the variables $P$, $V$, $T$,

assuming only:

- $T \propto V$ when $P$ is constant (1st Gay-Lussac law)
- $T \propto P$ when $V$ is constant (2nd Gay-Lussac law)

then

- $P \propto{1\over V}$ when $T$ is constant (Boyle's law)
- $PV \propto T$ for any $P, V, T$

If this is correct, it seems very tidy and compact so why do most of more rigorous textbooks take Boyle's law as an experimental assumption instead? This way only three experimental laws (these two along with Avogadro's) are needed to justify the importance of the ideal gas model.

Comment: Aren't all three laws (Boyle, Gay-Lussac & Charles) derived from observations?

Comment: That's what I thought, but apparently the first is only a confirmation of the other two that imply it, it isn't theoretically indipendent and can be derived from them

Comment: I'd find that hard to believe since Boyles law was published in the mid 1600s and the other two in the early 1800s. It seems to me that all three can be derived from the other two as the ideal has law relates all three variables.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an agreement about which ones are the fundamental laws and which one is the derived one? Ignoring any historical factor, maybe by selecting the two with the most reliable experiments backing them, and leaving the third as a consequence.

Comment: Wouldn't the ideal gas law be the fundamental relation? And the three experiments follow from that one relation?

Comment: I have had similar issues with the foundations of dynamics. When I study for my exams I always get caught up in choosing which way round I like the definitions to go, this is a particularly big waste of time as I like to compare different sources. It's good to have an open mind, but sometimes it's a struggle just to find the most generally accepted version in physics. (Maybe I'd make a better mathematician...)

Comment: The ideal gas law can be derived from merging them like I stated in the post, it's just another way of seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done mathematically.  Let T = T(P,V).  Then, if T is proportional to P at constant V, then $$\frac{T}{P}=F(V)$$.  Therefore, $T=PF(V)$.  Now, if T is proportional to V at constant P, then $$\frac{T}{V}=P\frac{F(V)}{V}=kP$$In the above equation, $F(V)/V$ must be a constant in order for the right hand side to be independent of V.  So T=kPV.